# Storing a List into Python Sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to scrape form field IDs using Beautiful Soup like this

```
 for link in BeautifulSoup(content, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('input')):
    if link.has_key('id'):
        print link['id']
```

Lets us assume that it returns something like

```
username
email
password
passwordagain
terms
button_register
```

I would like to write this into Sqlite3 DB.

What I will be doing down the line in my application is... Use these form fields' IDs and try to do a POST may be. The problem is.. there are plenty of sites like this whose form field IDs I have scraped. So the relation is like this...

```
Domain1 - First list of Form Fields for this Domain1
Domain2 - Second list of Form Fields for this Domain2
.. and so on
```

What I am unsure here is... How should I design my column for this kind of purpose? Will it be OK if I just create a table with two columns - say

```
COL 1 - Domain URL (as TEXT)
COL 2 - List of Form Field IDs (as TEXT)
```

One thing to be remembered is... Down the line in my application I will need to do something like this...

**Pseudocode**

```
If Domain is "http://somedomain.com":
    For ever item in the COL2 (which is a list of form field ids):
         Assign some set of values to each of the form fields & then make a POST request
```

Can any one guide, please?

**EDITed on 22/07/2011 - Is My Below Database Design Correct?**

I have decided to have a solution like this. What do you guys think?

I will be having three tables like below

**Table 1**

```
Key Column (Auto Generated Integer) - Primary Key
Domain as TEXT
```

Sample Data would be something like:

```
1   http://url1.com
2   http://url2.com
3   http://url3.com
```

**Table 2**

```
Domain (Here I will be using the Key Number from Table 1)
RegLink - This will have the registeration link (as TEXT)
Form Fields (as Text)
```

Sample Data would be something like:

```
1   http://url1.com/register    field1
1   http://url1.com/register    field2
1   http://url1.com/register    field3
2   http://url2.com/register    field1
2   http://url2.com/register    field2
2   http://url2.com/register    field3
3   http://url3.com/register    field1
3   http://url3.com/register    field2
3   http://url3.com/register    field3
```

**Table 3**

```
Domain (Here I will be using the Key Number from Table 1)
Status (as TEXT)
User (as TEXT)
Pass (as TEXT)
```

Sample Data would be something like:

```
1   Pass    user1   pass1
2   Fail    user2   pass2
3   Pass    user3   pass3
```

Do you think this table design is good? Or are there any improvements that can be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the ids:

```
ids = (link['id'] for link in
        BeautifulSoup(content, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('input')) 
         if link.has_key('id'))
```

And this should show you how to save them, load them, and do something to each. This uses a single table and just inserts one row for each field for each domain. It's the simplest solution, and perfectly adequate for a relatively small number of rows of data.

```
from itertools import izip, repeat
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''create table domains
(domain text, linkid text)''')

domain_to_insert = 'domain_name'
ids = ['id1', 'id2']
c.executemany("""insert into domains
      values (?, ?)""", izip(repeat(domain_to_insert), ids))
conn.commit()

domain_to_select = 'domain_name'
c.execute("""select * from domains where domain=?""", (domain_to_select,))

# this is just an example
def some_function_of_row(row):
    return row[1] + ' value'

fields = dict((row[1], some_function_of_row(row)) for row in c)
print fields
c.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am just trying to understand this code... generator object, izip are new to me. I am googling and learning as I try to execute & understand your code. Thanks!

Comment: You can just as easily use a `for` loop to get the ids, and another `for` loop to insert them (using `for id in ids: c.execute("insert into domains values (?, ?)", (domain_to_insert, id))` if those are making things more complex and you want to focus on the database stuff.

Comment: hey, no.. nothing makes it complex. Like you already know, I am new to Python. Been just a week. So trying to gather & learn every little possible thing.. like using , instead of + in a print, etc. I just do not want a working piece of code but a robust piece of code. That's why trying to learn & understand your way of code as well. Really, thank you!

Comment: Sure I will. I just want to try out each of these suggestion provided here. Once I am finalized with a solution I will update the thread and also accept a solution. Thanks!

Comment: This solution consumes a lot of space because the domain is stored for each field id. See my solution how to normalize the database model.

Comment: @ms4py Yes, I said in my answer "It's the __simplest__ solution, and perfectly adequate for a relatively small number of rows of data." If you've only got a few thousand rows, you don't need to worry about space or `select` speed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a normalization problem in your table.

Using 2 tables with

```
TABLE domains
int id primary key
text name

TABLE field_ids
int id primary key
int domain_id foreign key ref domains
text value
```

is a better solution.

Comment: oh.. So you mean, in the first table **domains** I will have only the domain urls. While in the second table **fields_ids** I will have rows like domain1 - field1, domain1 - field2, domain - field3, .. domain1 - fieldn... likewise domain2 - field1, domain2 - field2, .. domain2... fieldn, etc. This sounds good too. Thanks!

Comment: @Bhavani-Kannan: You make a key for each domain. You pair these up in one database. Then you use those keys in the second database pair with each field, since it's way faster to look things up by a key than it is to look them up by just the domain. If you want to do it with just the domain name and no key, you only need one table, and you can take a look at my answer.

Comment: I have EDITed my question with what I have decided to do. So I am planning to do something like `c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS base (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Domain TEXT, PR INTEGER)')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS register (Domain INTEGER, Reglink TEXT, Fields TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(Domain) REFERENCES base(ID)')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS regdata (Domain INTEGER, Status TEXT, Username TEXT, Password TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(Domain) REFERENCES base(ID)')` Do you guys think this is an optimized way?

Answer (score 1):

Proper database design would suggest you have a table of URLs, and a table of fields, each referenced to a URL record. But depending on what you want to do with them, you could pack lists into a single column. See [the docs for how to go about that](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#using-adapters-to-store-additional-python-types-in-sqlite-databases).

Is sqlite a requirement? It might not be the best way to store the data. E.g. if you need random-access lookups by URL, the [shelve module](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) might be a better bet. If you just need to record them and iterate over the sites, it might be simpler to store as CSV.

Comment: There is nothing like a requirement at all because I have no client. I am doing all this to simply the daily routines that I do in my daily life. So, it is nothing more than learning you can say. I will go through the links you have provided. Especially I wanted to use SQlite3 because I just spent couple of days learning the very basics of it. The Shelve Module is new to me. I will go through the documents. Thanks!

Comment: `shelve` always seems to be new to people. It's rather limited, but if all you need is a key-value store (like a dict on disk), it's easy to use.